# How to show all records from 2 tables in same database?

Tags: mysql, command-line

I am making a database over the classes I need to take to finish my BS degree. I have 2 tables in my database, "gereport" and "majorreport". Both tables have the same information in them, but I wanted them separate. My problem, I try to get an overview of all the classes I still need to take that are both ge and major classes. I have tried to do the following:

```
mysql> SELECT gereport.*, majorreport.* FROM gereport, majorreport;
```

This is the result I get:

```
+-------+-----------+-------+------+-------+---------+-------+------+
| area  | class     | units | done | area  | class   | units | done |
+-------+-----------+-------+------+-------+---------+-------+------+
| A1    | TRANSFER  |  2.66 | yes  | LD    | CS 46A  |     3 | yes  |
| A1    | TRANSFER  |  2.66 | yes  | LD    | CS 46B  |     3 | yes  |
| A1    | TRANSFER  |  2.66 | yes  | LD    | CS 46A  |     6 | yes  |
| A1    | TRANSFER  |  2.66 | yes  | LD    | CS 49J  |     3 | yes  |
```

Fast forward, I get a list of:
    464 rows in set (0.00 sec)

It's supposed to only have 45 rows total. I'm quite new to mysql. Is there any command I can use to make the rows in each table show in one table? I can't have a primary key, since some classes can be in several areas, and some areas have several classes.

In short, I guess what I want, is for the tables to join downwards, and not sideways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a union:

From the MySQL docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
>   into a single result set.

```
select * from gereport
UNION
select * from majorreport;
```

Note that, in my opinion, it's good practice to be explicit about columns so that it's clear that columns are "stacked" correctly. So I'd write the query like this:

```
select area, class, units, done from gereport
UNION
select area, class, units, done from majorreport;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a `UNION`.

```
SELECT * FROM gereport
UNION
SELECT * FROM majorreport;
```

Note that this query is not optimized. If you were running a large DB that constantly had to do this query, I would add some indexes and re-organize the database so you can make some joins which would be much more efficient.

Comment: Well, I knew this would be a database of less than 100 records, so in this case I chose to do it this way on purpose. Thanks for the heads up though :-)